# .Net Core 2.1 not reading User Secrets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am running a .net core 2.1 application on a mac and I am trying to access my connections string which should be overridden by my user secrets. The .csproj file includes a guid

```
<UserSecretsId>{{Secret Guid}}</UserSecretsId>
```

Add the user secret keys

```
dotnet user-secrets set "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection" "Secret Connection String"
```

I create the configuration which reads from my appsettings.json file perfectly however it does not replaces the default values with the ones from my user secrets.

```
// this is done so I build my configurations in a class library
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Single(o => o.EntryPoint != null);

var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    // .AddUserSecrets<Program>() -> This does not work either
    .AddUserSecrets(assembly, optional: false);

configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

Console.WriteLine(configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
```

As I stated previously trying to access the values it does not replace the values with the user secrets values. Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The order you add configuration sources to your `ConfigurationBuilder` is *important* - those added later override those added earlier. In your example, you're calling `AddUserSecrets` before `AddJsonFile`, which results in your JSON file values *overriding* your user secrets values.

For the sake of completeness, here's a fixed version:

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

// configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets<Program>(); -> This does not work either
configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets(assembly, optional: false);
```

In light of this, you might also want to move the `AddEnvironmentVariables` call to run later in the configuration setup.